# What's causing this slow/delayed audio playback in Safari?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, safari

```
var audio = new Audio('data:audio/wav;base64,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');

setInterval(function() {
    audio.play();
}, 50);
```

This code works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari there's a delay of over a second between each sound. I can't figure out why this would be, as far as I can tell there are no compatibility issues. I want to play sounds at a precise time and at a reasonably fast delay in a game that I'm making, how can I get this working?

Comment: Please check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58813681/2668045

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea why, but adding AudioContext removes the delay.

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
```

Found out by accident, works for me. Go figure.

Safari version 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9).

Comment: This also fixed a weird delay I had on Safari when setting `audio.currentTime`. Thanks!