# Play html5 video tag simultaneously on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

i have this weird behavior on html5 video tag.
I have 4 videos, that i want to play at the same time.
So i create my own control bar to play/pause, so when play button is clicked, all 4 videos is played, same as pause button.

On safari, it has weird problem, the video didn't play at the same time, 1 or 2 videos have delay when i click play, so not all videos playing at the same time.

On Chrome and Firefox it's working allright, what's wrong with safari?

I'm using javascript `.play()` function to play all videos.

I also make sure the video is loaded before playing it. Something like,

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto">
    <source src="asset/video/al_vertrag_kranken_v1_part1.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    <source src="asset/video/al_vertrag_kranken_v1_part1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="asset/video/al_vertrag_kranken_v1_part1.webm" type='video/webm' />
</video>

video_1 = document.getElementById('example_video_1');

if (video_1.readyState == 4 && video_2.readyState == 4 && video_3.readyState == 4 && video_4.readyState == 4) {
    video_1.play();
    video_2.play();
    video_3.play();
}
```

there's 3 more video tag like that, that 1 is only example.

Comment: Probably because different videos have different pre-loading times

Comment: i already use `.readyState` function before playing the video. But still not working.
i will edit my question

Comment: How is your setup-code for the video elements?

Comment: edited my question again, please take a look, thank you :)

Comment: Are all videos delayed the same time? like: Video 1 <--> Video 2 ( 2sec ), Video 2 <--> Video 3 ( 2sec ) etc..

Comment: Surprisingly difficult. The closest I've got on Safari is within ~27ms of each other, compared to ~3ms on Chrome. What's the use-case -- just how exact does it need to be?

Comment: have you found the answer @morgan9999 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I Noticed you are using Videojs library (your video has the class "video-> js"

Please, check this fiddle i´ve prepared for you to test this with [Videojs](http://www.videojs.com/)

I think is what you need ;)

As you can see, the problem with safari is always happening. In chrome or others it´s working perfectly. It seems to be produced by a delay it has when starting playback of videos. The same happens when playback starts for audio.

maybe in [that stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811429/html5-audio-tag-on-safari-has-a-delay) you´ll find your solution. It seems that the audio solution is to generate a swf (FLASH) object and to play videos with it (don´t know about it but i´ll try to prepare another edit to the answer with an example)

**EDIT**

> I´ve found this js library  https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf I´ll try with it to solve!

Hope it helps to you.

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

  alert("FIRST LOADING VIDEOS AND WAITING");


  var vid = document.getElementById("example_video_1");
  vid.oncanplay = function() {
    startplay(1);
  };
  var vid2 = document.getElementById("example_video_2");
  vid2.oncanplay = function() {
    startplay(1);
  };
  var vid3 = document.getElementById("example_video_3");
  vid3.oncanplay = function() {
    startplay(1);

  };
  var vid4 = document.getElementById("example_video_4");
  vid4.oncanplay = function() {
    startplay(1);
  };

});


var loaded = 0;

function startplay(num) {
  // alert(num);
  loaded += 1;

  if (loaded == 4) {

    document.getElementById("example_video_1").play();
    document.getElementById("example_video_2").play();
    document.getElementById("example_video_3").play();
    document.getElementById("example_video_4").play();

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<video id="example_video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<video id="example_video_3" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<video id="example_video_4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Comment: Hi, i'm curious to know if you solve it like you said in you edit ?

Comment: Did you find any problem? If did please report and will be glad to solve!

Comment: On mobile you can't play simultaneous video on safari, and no solution found.

Comment: I searched a little, and found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41838950/3617531 I up-voted It. Please review. I think the patch you need has been recently cooked ;)

Answer (score 2):

**As per Safari HTML Audio Video Guide**

Syncing Multiple Media Elements Together Until the advent of media controllers, ensuring that two or more videos played at precisely the same time was a challenging endeavor.

Media controllers let you group any number of audio and/or video elements so that they can be managed by a universal set of controls, and also so that they can be kept in perfect sync, even if a network hiccup occurs.

To create a media controller, simply add the `mediagroup` attribute to all of the elements you wish to sync
together. The value you choose to assign to `mediagroup` is up to you—as long as the value is the same for each slaved element, a media controller will be created implicitly.

```
<video src="video.m4v" width="960" height="600"
mediagroup="masterController"></video>
```

Most of the same **functions**, **attributes**, and **events** available to audio and video elements are also available to media controllers. Instead of calling `play()` or `pause()` directly on the video itself, you call them on the
media controller.

Controlling Media with JavaScript
Syncing Multiple Media Elements Together
2012-12-13 | Copyright © 2012 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.

```
var myVideo = document.querySelector('video');
var mediaController = myVideo.controller;
mediaController.play();
```

Note: Two attributes that aren’t supported by media controllers are loop and autoplay.

Accessing the controller object on any of the slaved media elements will return a controller of the grouped
elements. You can also create a media controller entirely in JavaScript without needing to modify the attributes
of your HTML:

```
var myVideos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
var mediaController = new MediaController();
myVideos[0].controller = mediaController;
myVideos[1].controller = mediaController;
mediaController.play();
```

If one video stalls or stutters, the other videos will automatically pause to wait for the lagging video to catch up. When the video buffers and is ready to play, the remaining videos will resume in sync.

I hope this helps...

And you can find this doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf)

Comment: maybe you could just add `if ( !window.MediaController ) return;`

Comment: Yes @Kaiido. Yet the thing is we can use mediagroup attribute to address the issue in safari.

Comment: then add  `if( !myVideo.controller ) return;` to avoid TypeError in other browsers But yes it's a nice solution and I didn't know about this MediaController.

Comment: This solution is not working at all. Only one video plays.

Answer (score 1):

Try to monitor `canplay` event on all 4 elements. Something like

```
// Event trigger counter
var i = 0;
$('video').on('canplay', function(){
    i += 1;
    // Start playback when everything is ready
    if (i === 4) {
        $('video').each(function(){
            this.play();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: not working, some video still delayed. it's really weird

Comment: Hmmm, yep, it's totally weird.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like playing multiple video simultaneously is not currently supported on Safari...

From Safari HTML5 Audio and video guide :

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW10

> **Multiple Simultaneous Audio or Video Streams**
>
> Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single
>   audio or video stream at any time. Playing more than one video—side by
>   side, partly overlapping, or completely overlaid—is not currently
>   supported on iOS devices. Playing multiple simultaneous audio streams
>   is also not supported. You can change the audio or video source
>   dynamically, however. See [Replacing a Media Source Sequentially](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5)
>   for details.

Comment: "Currently, all devices running iOS are limited to playback of a single audio or video stream at any time. Playing more than one video—side by side, partly overlapping, or completely overlaid—is not currently supported on iOS devices"
i guess you talk about mobile safari, my question is about mac os safari

Comment: I did a little search, and found this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/41838950/3617531 I up-voted It.  I think the patch you need has been recently cooked ;)