# Safari Desktop HTML5 Audio Tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, delay

do you have any information related to the audio tag on MacOS Safari. The issue I am having is when I use audio.play() the sound is delayed 100ms - a full second. It is as the sound is being reloaded from the server each time.

I am only using one file and I was hoping maybe there was a work around for this things I tried was to play the audio file and pause it before the end and them move the position and the play the audio again but I beleive the play() function in safari actually reloaded the file.

Thank you!

Comment: Which one, 100ms or 1 second, they aren't equal.

Comment: Please check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58813681/2668045