# Delay in playing audio (mp3) in iOS 13 safari/chrome browser

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs

Is there a way to reduce (get rid of) the delay in playing audio (mp3) in iOS 13 safari/chrome browser?  I have tried setting preload to "none" and also to "auto" but it doesn't seem to work in anyway. I'm using react h5 audio player.

Answer (score 0):

I later found a hack to get rid of the delay. If the mp3 file is converted to 128kbps (or much better to 64kbps), this delay is gone. I hope this solution works out for others as well.

Comment: Did you checked if its the issue with file size or not ? As downloading big file can delay it too as generally higher the bitsize ,higher the size of file

Comment: Yeah I did check that too. Smaller file is a good way to go but doesn't guarantee the instant playback on browsers in iOS devices. Reducing the bitrate guarantees delay free playback.

Answer (score 0):

I converted my audio file to base64 encoding so the audio is now inline text and doesn't need to be downloaded as an additional http call with latency.

Here's a [base64 converter](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/audio).

Naturally this solution doesn't work for every scenario, but if you've got a small/short audio file that doesn't require a lot of audio clarity, then the solution can work quite well.

Answer (score -1):

Try add:

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54119854/2364154 l

Comment: The source says it solves the problem for desktop safari. I did not face much of an issue in desktop safari but in mobile safari in iphone. I'll still try it out.