# HTML5 Audio on Desktop Safari: Long Delay

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

I'm working on a website with a music playlist. The code is very straightforward, I use one `<audio>` tag with `preload="true"`, then whenever a track is clicked on the playlist I use JS to change the source, then I load and play the track with `audio.load()` and `audio.play()`. This works fine on all browsers except for Safari (on Desktop). With a fast internet connection, there is a 2-3s delay before the audio starts playing. With a slower connection it takes up to 60 seconds before the music starts playing. It seems to me that Safari loads the full mp3 file before it starts the playback, while the other browsers can stream it flawlessly even with a very slow internet.

The mp3s are as small as they can be (128kbsp), the file sizes are around 1-2MB.

Is there a way to change Safari's behaviour and stream the audio file?

Comment: @Kerman, I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Same problem. Did you guys find any solution for this?

Comment: Didn't find a solution to reduce delay, but it's possible to measure it and compensate for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75620751/1052640

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have resolved the problem by setting preload="none" in Audio tag.

Comment: Let's wait for op confirmation, thanks for your contribution. If you can give an explanation it will be great.